# C++something went wrong

Tags: visual-c++

```
class Origami {
public:
    class FoldingAction {
    public:
        const int foldID;
        const std::vector<double> ppoint;
        const std::vector<double> pnormal;
        const int polygonIndex;
        const int phi;

        FoldingAction();
        FoldingAction(int foldID, vector<double>& ppoint, vector<double>& pnormal, int polygonIndex, int phi): foldID(foldID), ppoint(ppoint), pnormal(pnormal), polygonIndex(polygonIndex), phi(phi) {}
        void execute(Origami origami) {
            switch (foldID) {
            case 1:
                origami.internalReflectionFold(ppoint, pnormal);
                break;
            case 2:
                origami.internalRotationFold(ppoint, pnormal, phi);
                break;
            case 3:
                origami.internalReflectionFold(ppoint, pnormal, polygonIndex);
                break;
            case 4:
                origami.internalRotationFold(ppoint, pnormal, phi, polygonIndex);
                break;
            case 5:
                origami.internalRotationFold(ppoint, pnormal, 0);
                break;
            case 6:
                origami.internalMutilation(ppoint, pnormal);
                break;
            case 7:
                origami.internalMutilation(ppoint, pnormal, polygonIndex);
                break;
            }
        }
    };
        void internalReflectionFold(vector<double>& ppoint, vector<double>& pnormal);

    void internalReflectionFold(vector<double>& ppoint, vector<double>& pnormal, int polygonIndex);

    int internalRotationFold(vector<double>& ppoint, vector<double>& pnormal, int phi);

    void internalRotationFold(vector<double>& ppoint, vector<double>& pnormal, int phi, int polygonIndex);

    void internalMutilation(vector<double>& ppoint, vector<double>& pnormal);

    void internalMutilation(vector<double>& ppoint, vector<double>& pnormal, int polygonIndex);
}
```

in this class ,there always went wrong(case 1:origami.internalReflectionFold(ppoint, pnormal);break;).It said:There are no overloaded function instances that match the parameter list

The parameter types are: (const std:: vector<double, std: allocator>, const std:: vector<double, std: allocator>)

The object type is: Origami.
I do not know how to solve it after tring every solvtion i know.

I just want to know how to make it not Error reporting.

Comment: `ppoint` is `const vector<double>` but `internalReflectionFold` takes a `vector<double>&`, non-const. Same with `pnormal` parameter. If `internalReflectionFold` doesn't actually modify its parameters, make them `const`. If it does need to modify its parameters, drop `const` from data members.